# How to disable USB device on Linux Mint?

Tags: linux, usb-drive

I have consecutive log messages:

```
 usb-storage 2-1.5:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
 usb-storage 2-1.5:1.0: Quirks match for vid 05e3 pid 0723: 8000
 scsi host25: usb-storage 2-1.5:1.0
 usb 2-1.5: USB disconnect, device number 49
 usb 2-1.5: new high-speed USB device number 50 using ehci-pci
 usb 2-1.5: new high-speed USB device number 53 using ehci-pci
 usb 2-1.5: new high-speed USB device number 54 using ehci-pci
 usb 2-1.5: new high-speed USB device number 57 using ehci-pci
 usb 2-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0723
 usb 2-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=2
 usb 2-1.5: Product: USB Storage
 usb 2-1.5: Manufacturer: Generic
 usb 2-1.5: SerialNumber: 000000009451
 usb-storage 2-1.5:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
 usb-storage 2-1.5:1.0: Quirks match for vid 05e3 pid 0723: 8000
 scsi host26: usb-storage 2-1.5:1.0
 scsi 26:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  STORAGE DEVICE   9451 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
 sd 26:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
 sd 26:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
 usb 2-1.5: USB disconnect, device number 57
 usb 2-1.5: new high-speed USB device number 58 using ehci-pci
 usb 2-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0723
 usb 2-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=2
 usb 2-1.5: Product: USB Storage
 usb 2-1.5: Manufacturer: Generic
 usb 2-1.5: SerialNumber: 000000009451
 usb-storage 2-1.5:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
 usb-storage 2-1.5:1.0: Quirks match for vid 05e3 pid 0723: 8000
 scsi host27: usb-storage 2-1.5:1.0
 scsi 27:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  STORAGE DEVICE   9451 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
 sd 27:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
 sd 27:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

This disturb me because of sound of plugged/unplugged device, even when sound is muted (I setup 0% volume, and the sound icon in taskbar is grayed)

How to prevent this?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww: yes, those are better. May you please move topic there?

Answer (score -1):

This command seems helps me:

```
echo "2-1.5:1.0" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb-storage/2-1.5:1.0/driver/unbind
```